# Python: Mechanize Form Processing HTTP Error 405

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am currently testing a script for Python programmatic web browsing with mechanize [from this neat book](http://corepython.com/) and have come across an error I can't seem to fix. Basically, I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()

#home page
rsp = br.open('http://us.pycon.org/2011/home/')
print '\n***', rsp.geturl()

page = rsp.read()
assert 'Log in' in page, 'Log in not in page'
rsp = br.follow_link(text_regex='Log in')

#login page
print '\n***', rsp.geturl()
print 'Confirm at least a login form; submit invalid creds'
assert  len(list(br.forms())) > 1, 'no forms on this page'

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = 'xasdxx' #wrong login on purpose
br.form['password'] = 'xxasdfx' #wrong password on purpose
rsp = br.submit()

#login page with error
print '\n***', rsp.geturl()
```

The script is identical to the one in the book. Every time I run it I get the following error:

[image]

I have also reviewed [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369097/http-error-405-500-in-python-mechanize-using-mechanize-auto-login-one-website) but there seems to be no solution there...

**EDIT: I found [more posts](http://www.solutionoferror.com/python/http-error-405-500-in-python-mechanize-using-mechanize-auto-login-one-webs-104328.asp) with a similar problem but no concrete solution.**

Help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

~Aivoric

**SOLUTION: As shown in the answer below by Foo Bar, my IP was blocked and therefore wasn't allowing me to do anything on the website. I then adjusted the script to run on https://www.rememberthemilk.com and everything worked fine:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website gave `405` on `mechanize`
It also gave `405` on `selenium` 
Then i tried to sign up and send a proper name, but signing up gave `405` as well.

either the site is broken or my ip (and yours) got blocked.

Comment: The OP is not controlling the server.

Comment: sorry my fault. i tried and got 405. tried selenium to see if it makes different 405. Tried to sign up and use a proper user name still 405. it maybe something wrong with their site or i was blocked.

Comment: try signup from a different ip. if you cant the website is broken, if you can then you are blocked.

Comment: But if you try to enter the website and the login form from a normal browser it works fine. If you enter the wrong credentials it gives you an error. I think something is wrong with the code...

Comment: Strange i tried to signup but i got 405. sounds related. do you use this url to login? https://us.pycon.org/2011/account/login/ because it says something about credential from other sites wont work

Comment: Foo Bar you are correct :) my IP was blocked. I just tried to sign up and it wasn't getting me. I then adjusted the script to run on the https://www.rememberthemilk.com website and it worked correctly! Thank you for your help :) I have posted the result as an EDIT to the question.

Comment: do you want the selenium script i tried? its less chanced to get blocked